# SSMS connection to Sybase ASE

Tags: ssms, sap-ase

Is there a way to connect to a Sybase (ASE) database instance using Sql Server Management Studio 2008?
I tried using other tools to connect but they are very limited and would like to use SSMS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this tool:

[SqlDbx](http://www.sqldbx.com/)

It's great.

Answer (score 4):

As far as i know there is no way to use Microsoft's Server Management Studio. And if you are honest it doesnt make a lot sense either. why should sybase/sap design their servers to work with an application provided from a competitor.

personally i prefer to use isql as client software for sybase servers. if you wish to have a GUI may Sybase Central is an option for you.

Comment: I found SQL Explorer to be a great tool. http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipsesql/

Comment: Sybase and MSSQL come from the same roots, Microsoft originally licensed the "Sybase SQL Server" code for their own RDBMS.  SQL Server 2000 (ie: version 7) was the first to diverge from that shared codebase, so it's easy to see why someone would assume SSMS 2008 (ie: version 9) might be able to connect natively to a Sybase instance.